# jquery :Save img src path to local storage for selected image

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

- Hello , i Have some basic code to change the background for my app

  i need to save the path of selected image for this img src of

  this div **id="productImage"**  When the **USER 1** Select any image From

  the list  to local storage and get the current selected image after

  reload the page form local storage For example> local storage data

  key background-path:background/image1.png

  Thanks for help

```js
 function Selectbk() {
  $('.thumbnail').click(function () {
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('empty.png');
    $('#productImage').attr('src', src);
  });
 }
```

```css
ul.chat-gallery {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: -0%;
}
ul.chat-gallery img {
    max-width: 60px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="productImage" src="https://vps.nemra-1.com/v4/mobile/img/background/empty.png" style="height:30%;width:40%">
 <a class="cancel" href="#"></a>
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Do you like To Switch Background?</h2>
  <div class="content">
        <ul class="chat-gallery">
            <li>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"  onclick="Selectbk()"><img src="https://ak6.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1027713866/thumb/10.jpg"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#" onclick="Selectbk()"><img src="https://ak6.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1022870776/thumb/11.jpg"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`$().data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of `localStorage`:

```js
function Selectbk() {
  $('.thumbnail').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('empty.png');
    $('#productImage').attr('src', src);
    $('#productImage').data('src', src);
  });
}

$("button").click(function() {
  console.log($('#productImage').data('src'));
});
```

```css
ul.chat-gallery {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: -0%;
}

ul.chat-gallery img {
  max-width: 60px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="cancel" href="#"></a>
<button>get src</button>
<div class="popup">
  <h2>Do you like To Switch Background?</h2>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="chat-gallery">
      <li>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#" onclick="Selectbk()"><img src="https://ak6.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1027713866/thumb/10.jpg"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#" onclick="Selectbk()"><img src="https://ak6.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1022870776/thumb/11.jpg"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<img id="productImage" src="https://vps.nemra-1.com/v4/mobile/img/background/empty.png" style="height:30%;width:40%">
```

Comment: idont wont to get src..i need to save the src to localStorage when the user select image from list and restored again after reload the page inside  id="productImage" src="